# Does evaluation metric not matter for training a model? And why?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, cart, model-evaluation

I think I'm misunderstanding something with training ML tree models.  There's a bunch of [evaluation metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) we can use.

It seems like this metric however is only used after training, which does not seem intuitive for me.  Perhaps we want to prioritise precision.  Perhaps we want to prioritise recall, etc.  Doesn't the training algorithm need to be aware of this, in the same way a track runner would want to know whether to train for speed or distance?

I'm trying different evaluation metrics in a xgboost classifier and it doesn't seem to be making a single difference to the fitted model.

Comment: Do you mean why one might use crossentropy loss for training but F1 score for mode evaluation, so why not train to maximize F1 instead of minimize crossentropy?

Comment: @Dave perhaps that's what I'm getting at.  Let's say I have one model that I want to perform well with respect to f1, and another model that I want to perform well with respect to Cohen's Kappa.  I don't understand why these models would not be trained differently.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You can configure the loss via [learning task parameters](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters).

Comment: @frank I can indeed set both `objective`, and `eval_metric` in the model.  My confusion is that eval_metric does not seem to make a spot of difference during training.  I gave it a custom evaluation metric that always returns a value of 1, and the trained model (on same dataset with same hyperparameters) was exactly the same.

Comment: In general, different objectives do lead to different results.

Comment: I'd agree with that, but there is a distinction to be made between objective and evaluation metric, and this concerns the latter

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide a Minimal Working Example?